# Wrong element width, when using .affix

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/6fuj215r/) you can see, that when we scrolling down, search field receive large width. If I delete  tag (with search glyph icon) - all working. And I get the same problem with other tags, like , and other elements classes, like .panel-group, .panel-heading and e.t.c. How can I fix it?

HTML code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
  .affix {
      top: 20px;
}
</style>

<body>
<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:#2196F3;color:#fff;height:200px;">
  <h1>Bootstrap Affix Example</h1>
</div>
<br>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <nav class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="205">
        <div class="input-group">
            <i class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
            <input name="search" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="search">
        </div>
        <li>TEST 1</li>
        <li>TEST 2</li>
        <li>TEST 3</li>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="col-sm-9">   
      <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
      <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
      <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
      <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
      <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
      <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
      <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
      <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
      <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
      <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
      <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
      <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
      <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
      <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to address it is to add `left: 15px; right: 15px;` to match the parent col's padding, which is what controls the width when the element is not affixed.

```html
<title>Bootstrap Example</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
  .affix {
    top: 20px;
    left: 15px;
    right: 15px;
  }
</style>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:#2196F3;color:#fff;height:200px;">
    <h1>Bootstrap Affix Example</h1>
    <h3>Fixed (sticky) vertical sidenav on scroll</h3>
    <p>Scroll this page to see how the left navigation menu behaves with data-spy="affix".</p>
    <p><strong>The left menu sticks to the page when you have scrolled a specified amount of pixels.</strong></p>
  </div>
  <br>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <nav class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="205">
          <div class="input-group">
            <i class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
            <input name="search" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="search">
          </div>
          <li>TEST 1</li>
          <li>TEST 2</li>
          <li>TEST 3</li>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
        <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
        <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
        <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
        <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
        <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
        <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
        <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
        <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
        <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
        <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
        <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
        <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
        <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Dzam Oh, I thought you were referring to the width in the affixed/non-affixed state. Is this what you're going for? jsfiddle.net/6fuj215r/8

Comment: Yes, it works. But only for <I> tag. And not working for panel. I have updated [example](https://jsfiddle.net/6fuj215r/10/). I think that problem in the <a> tag. All elements get with equal of maximum width of <a> element. Is any issue for this?

Comment: @Dzam your icon/input seem fine in that jsfiddle. What's the problem exactly? What do you want it to look like instead?

Comment: problem with .panel-group and it <a> elements. And problem the same like with search icon. When I scroll down, all panel elements get with, that equal maximum with of <a> element.